# Why is my DataList flow still outputting a table?

Tags: asp.net, datalist

I am new to .net, and am tasked with customizing an eCommerce site that attaches to our SAP B1 server.  The output of products is currently accomplished through a Datalist which creates output in a table.  I have changed the RepeatLayout="Flow" in an effort to use a ul li structure instead of tables.  Why is my output still coming in the form of tables?

Comment: Which framework version your application use?

Comment: @YuriyRozhovetskiy ".NET Version 2.0.50727.5456"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either `Table` or `Flow` in .Net 2. Instruction is [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.repeatlayout.aspx).

`Flow` will render with span tag.

`UnorderedList` and `OrderedList` [throws exception](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/654309/error-on-changing-datalist-controls-repeat-layout-property) even in .Net 4.

However, you can use repeater control for your desired ul and li layout.

```
<asp:Repeater  ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <HeaderTemplate>
        <ul>
    </HeaderTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <%# Eval("FirstName")%>
            <%# Eval("LastName")%></li></ItemTemplate>
    <FooterTemplate>
        </ul></FooterTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: tried to convert from datalist to repeater but I get the following error Parser Error Message: The base class includes the field 'PartsListRepeater', but its type (System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataList) is not compatible with the type of control (System.Web.UI.WebControls.Repeater).

Comment: Look like somewhere in your code is still referencing as DataList instead of new Repeater control.

Comment: Thats the issue - this is not my code so I don't know it extremely well, so changing from DataList could prove very difficult.  Do you know why my datalist repeatlayout property of Flow is not working?

Comment: By default, RepeatLayout="Flow" renders with span tags. Please make sure if you use SkinID, it is not overriding RepeatLayout property.